# Web Scraping with Selenium on Python using Google Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scape a website to get some company information.  If the search result is there and matches the search term I would like to continue, if not, I would like to move on to the next company.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import notebook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import time, sleep
import datetime
import sys

url = "https://register.fca.org.uk/s/"
search_box_path = '//*[@id="search-form-search-section-main-input"]'
firm_checkbox_path = '//*[@id="search-form-search-options-radio-group"]/span[1]/label/span[1]'
searchterm = 'XXX Company'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\XXXX\Chrome Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,firm_checkbox_path)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(firm_checkbox_path).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_box_path).send_keys(searchterm)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_box_path).send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//* 
[@id="maincontent"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/h1/span[2]')))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/h1/span[2]')
check_result()
```

The issue is with the check_result function.  In this function I am just comparing the searchterm against the element.text of the element from the website.

```
def check_result():
    name= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/h1/span[2]')
    return name.text == searchterm:
```

This logic on its own works fine, but along with the code it give me false even though I know that the text I provide is equal to the element.text.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do a `print(repr(name.text), repr(searchterm))`. One or both may contain whitespace.

Comment: nope no white space:(  Interestingly, if I run the check_result() in a different line it works, it stops working when it is together with the rest of the code.

Comment: If it's in a function check if the searchterm has the value of the global value.